# What is the name for this type of URL attack?

Tags: php, attacks, url

Say a PHP page accepts URL path as a POST parameter (like the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28365447/413180)):

```
$path = $_POST['url_path'];

file_get_contents('http://example.com' . $path);
```

A maliicious user POSTs `url_path` as `@evil.com/stuff.html`.

As the code takes the user input and appends it without a [delimiter to end the username section](http://www.w3.org/TR/url-1/#url-writing) (e.g. `?`, `/`), `$path` ends up as:

```
http://example.com@evil.com/stuff.html
```

which means username `example.com` accessing `http://evil.com/stuff.html`.

Is there already a specific name for this type of attack? The closest I found was [Semantic URL attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL_attack), however this seems more syntaxic. It appears to be a type of URL obfuscation, however as it is on the server and not visible to the end-user in the address bar it is a slightly different type of attack to [Phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing).

Note: The code is also vulnerable to other types of domain manipulation such as appending something to change the interpretation to another top level domain (e.g. POSTing `.uk` to change `example.co`). So on that basis I would just call it a general string concatenation flaw rather than an attack specifically relating to URLs - however, I'd like to put this out to the floor.

Comment: Remote file inclusion? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability#Remote_File_Inclusion

Comment: Including the file as executable script is not a requirement of the scenario.

Comment: HTTP Request Smuggling? http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246928/HTTP%20Request%20Smuggling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server Side Request Forgery (SSRF) where the server makes a web request to a user controlled URL. MITRE has assigned this as [CWE-918](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/918.html).